# How to get key values in app.config properly?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm building an automated bot based on Selenium using Windows service template in Visual Studio. It's supposed to log in to an account very once in a while. It works fine hard coding the credentials, but it does not read the key values from `app.config` file after adding them manually via a second editor (Notepad in this case) not through explorer in Visual Studio!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Username" value="si**********" />
        <add key="Password" value="Ami*********" />
    </appSettings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the information from AppStings in development mode.

```
string value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's what I did. Still doesn't work. This is a windows service application, so I need to build it with empty values for the keys I already defined in app.config file. So a second guy with a different computer can add their own values. I tried it with appsettings.json file through a worker service template using IConfiguration and it worked, but I don't have a clue on how to do it in a windows service one.